# Javascript question: How do I calculate terminal coordinates from a lat/lng map coordinate given the distance and bearing

Tags: javascript, distance, latitude-longitude, bearing

I am writing a javascript program which requires calculation of a terminal lat/lng coordinate given:

1. source lat/lng coordinates
2. bearing
3. direction

signature required:

```
const getTerminalCoords(startCoords, bearing, distance) = () => {
  // mapping here
}
```

I have found lots of solutions in other languages even some using third party libraries but nothing cleanly using pure Javascript Math functions.

Any help or advice much appreciated.

Comment: bearing = direction.

Comment: @WaisKamal - Yes, sense 6(a) [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bearing).

Comment: Fundamentally, this is math. I'd expect the solutions in other languages to be fairly straightforward to translate to JavaScript...?

Comment: _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_ [tour]

Answer (score 1):

You could try the very useful [geolib.computeDestinationPoint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib#computedestinationpointpoint-distance-bearing-radius--earthradius), this will give you a destination point, given a bearing and distance:

```js
const startPoint = { latitude: 52.518611, longitude: 13.408056 };
const distanceMeters = 15000;
const bearing = 180;

const destination = geolib.computeDestinationPoint(
    startPoint,
    distanceMeters,
    bearing 
);

console.log("Start point:", startPoint);
console.log("Distance (m), bearing (°):", distanceMeters, ",", bearing);
console.log("Destination point:", destination);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/geolib@3.3.1/lib/index.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```